# How can I detect that a user signed into Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

Here is my scenario. When a user opens a browser and goes to facebook.com to sign himself in, I want to be able to detect that and init my Facebook application sign-in process.

Is that possible? I'm asking because I noticed that signing into Facebook itself doesn't get my app signed in automatically, which is not good.

I'd prefer JavaScript client code.

Comment: fbjs is the javascript API for FBML, which is deprecated in favor of the graph API. You can read about the new javascript SDK here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: thanks for the answers, I've tried the above event based handling, but doesn't seem to work.

i also read the javascript doc pointed out by Michael, the following paragraph is exciting but also confusing.  

"The Facebook JavaScript SDK allows you to remove user registration and sign-in by allowing the user to login to your site with their Facebook account. This is achieved by sharing the logged in user state between http://www.facebook.com/ and your site. A Facebook user remains logged in to your site as long as they are logged in to Facebook."

because based on my observation. sign int

Comment: **by sharing the logged in user state** is EXACTLY what you want, right? Besides a couple of mistakes on my example due to incorrect cutting and pasting (I was removing the non-relevant parts of an app of my own), the example was correct. Now those are fixed: I tested it and it works as expected. The example just reloads the page, but you can very well use an iframe instead.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** Here you have a **FULLY WORKING** example. The only thing you will need to do is to replace the APP_ID for whatever ID you get when sign your app at: http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and the port you may use for the localhost test. This detects when the user logs in even in another browser window. It is obviously extremely basic but proves the point that is feasible with the tools from the graph API.

---

You can add this code to detect when the user logs in. It is the same oauth log in whether the user clicks on a `<fb:login-button>` or logs directly onto facebook.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello App Engine</title>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></SCRIPT>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({
    appId  : APP_ID,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

/*
 * Authentication functions
 */
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
    welcomeMsg(response);
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
    alert ("Good bye!");
});

if (FB.getSession() != null) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response){
        console.log(response.name);
        welcomeMsg(response);

    })
} else {
    window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://localhost:8888"},5000);
}


function welcomeMsg(userData) {
    console.log ("Welcome " + userData.name);
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the auth.login event.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: hmmm, i always thought that was for when you sign in through a fb app. not for signing in directly through facebook.com

Comment: I know •auth.sessionChange works even when the session changes externally, so I'm guessing auth.login works as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Facebook images that you can see only if you're logged into Facebook. You can make the user attempt to load one of these images, and then detect if it loaded or not. It's a total trick.