# Save password popup chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on one chrome extension, which is required to show popup to save password of any particular website.

Please consider the following scenario
1)User opened www.facebook.com in browser.
2)Hit login button.
3)User is logged in. Chrome browser itself gave option "To save password".
4)At this stage I want my plugin to show some custom popup to save password.

Now the question is, how do my plugin come to know that user is logged in to some website.
Or how chrome browser comes to know that use is logged in to some website and show popup to save password.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For facebook: [How can I detect that a user signed into Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5609976) and for other sites invent something, there's no API for that.

Comment: Basically Chrome detects login forms with fields like "login", "username", "email", "password", etc that result in a page navigation or ajax request. This is the general pattern for signing into a site. It is however much more complex and Chrome has been slowly improving their process for years.

Comment: @abraham You are right..My chrome extension get to know that current web page is a login by detecting different HTML tags like <Form>, password field and all. I want to know How my plugin come to know that user has clicked the login button. Basically when user click login of any login page, my extension needs to show one popup asking to save password for that particular website. Hope I am able to explain my problem. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I am able to solve my problem.I am posting my answer,that might be helpful to others also. 
So in my case, I want to know that some user has logged in to some website.Here website is not fix, it could be any random website.

So, in order to know, user has clicked "Login" button, i am adding eventListener to window through my content script.

My code is as follows:

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
});

In the above code you have the element("this") which is clicked.
You can now check id, text,button title of "this" to check if it is "Login" or not.

If its "Login", then user hit the login button.
```